# How to solve zsh permission denied when adding MySQL to path?

Tags: mysql, zshrc

I'm trying to add mysql to path so that SQL commands interact with a MySQL database, however, permission denied. How do you solve this problem?

For macOS Catalina 10.15.6

**To find MySQL Location**

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

*This returns error*

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
zsh: permission denied: /Users/bolouie/.bash_profile
```

**Solution to zsh permission denied by specifying ~/.zshrc**

**To add MySQL to Path (permanently)**

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

*This returns*

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

****Set root user password for mysql login****

```
mysql -u root -p
```

*This returns error*

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

***Started MySQL Server to connect with "root" user password**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

*Enabled MySQL prompt*

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor...
mysql>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the command `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` and then run `source ~/.zshrc` instead?

Comment: That helped.  But now I get an error when setting the root user password for mysql login.

Comment: Have you started your mysql server using command `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`?

Answer (score 0):

First stop mysql if it's running by typing in terminal

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

then start mysql by typing

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

open a new terminal window

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

enter the password and then will run

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why `mysqld_safe` should be used instead of just `mysql`?